# How to change background color of an icon of multiple items dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

In my app i have 8 buttons in a horizontal list view.i want to highlight button after user clicked and to know present state.Means when user clicking first button it will highlighted with some background color.But,my problem is after clicking second button second is also highlighting but Previous button also not losing color.i want only highlighted Current Button.

Comment: how did we know, if u don't post code

Comment: had you tried Selector in android??

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by

1. Having a Button reference variable say `previousBtn` which points to previously changed Button and inside `onClick` of each Button you need to make the `previousBtn` default again.
2. Having a final Array of default color codes for all the Buttons, whenever the user clicks the Button you make a copy of this final Array. Change the index related to current Button and than using a loop apply the color codes to all the Buttons.

Each method has its own advantages and disadvantages you can select whichever suits your requirement.